# Refactoring database and preserve existing data best practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql, orm

I have been working on a very data intensive application that has around 250 tables. Recently there have been some design changes required. Some of the design changes require adding new tables and linking those up with existing tables (foregin key) in a 1-N manner for parent - child relationships (in ORM).

Take this example. Current design allows for one Rental Vehicle per Contract. New design requires multiple Vehicles in the same Contract with Multiple rates.

So the data in one table needs to be put in 2 additional tables now.

I have completed the changes to the schema but I can't deploy those changes to the test environment until I find a way to convert the existing data and put it in the new design format.

My current process.

1. Add 3 new Tables nContract, nContractedAsset, nContractRate
2. Copy information from Contract table into 3 new tables. Preserve primary key field on nContract table same as Contract table.
   Copy foregin key references / Indexes / Rights to nContract from Contract table
3. Drop Contract table
4. Rename nContract to Contract and so on.

**The only issue I have is I am not comfortable doing part 2 in SQL. I want to use the power of the ORM and .Net to do more intelligent and complex tasks for more complex scenarios than this example**

Is there a way I can write the data migration using ADO.Net or ORM for step 2?

What are best practices or the processes for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Row data is best handled within the database. What is it that bothers you? do you think your sql skills are lower then your orm skills?

Comment: It really is because I feel more comfortable handling objects and relationships. I can do SQL DDL and querying fine in SQL. But some of these requirements will require temporary tables to store information and then copied from there. I have more confidence in doing in memory calculations and intelligent processing of information when they're in objects.

Comment: "" The only issue I have is I am not comfortable doing part 2 in SQL. I want to use the power of the ORM and .Net to do more intelligent and complex tasks for more complex scenarios than this example "' there's no faster way (in terms of execution performance) than doing it in T-SQL. And you have transactions at your disposal, so you can retry as many times as required until your solution works (ROLLBACK if not, and start again). IMO doing that using some abstraction technology is just waste of energy and time. ORM is no more "intelligent" than T-SQL.

Comment: @Endrju not saying it is. End of the day it will translate to TSQL. Full roll back and transactions are supported in the ORM too. It's just the in memory processing I like about the Objects. I have access to a lot of data types and collections (eg. hash) in .NET which will make it a lot easier to do the things I want to do. If I'm doing purely in TSQL I will be need temporary tables do achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using FluentMigrator https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator

It allowed me to do Entity Framework like migrations (See: Ruby On Rails Active Records migrations)

Most of the DDL can be written in .NET in a fluent format. It supports UP and DOWN migrations wrapped up in transactions and even supports full SQL scripts for data migration.

Best thing about it is all your migration scripts can be put in source control and even tested.